# saveAs function not working in Safari?

Tags: javascript, pdf, safari, cross-browser, blob

I am trying to display a base64 PDF in an iFrame after a user generates it. For some reason it is extremely unresponsive in Safari and does not display correctly.

My workaround is to detect Safari (among other things) and save a blob. I've tested it on Chrome and Firefox but when the code executes in Safari it just ignores the save as.

Here is the code it should execute:

```
if(info.browser == 'safari'){
    var d = confirm("Click ok to download PDF");
    if(d == true){
        window.saveAs(blob, 'compare_report.pdf');
    }
    else{return;}
}
```